# c++20 import my own cpp file's module failed: module not found

Tags: c++, import, module, c++20

I'm on ubuntu with clang-14/gcc-12 and I have 2 cpp files: MyFun.cpp

```
export module cppcon; 
namespace ns_CppCon { 
    auto GetWelcomeHelper() {  return "Welcome to CppCon 2019!";  } 
    export auto GetWelcome() { return GetWelcomeHelper();} 
}
```

And UseFun.cpp

```
// main.cpp 
#include<iostream>
import cppcon; 
int main(){ 
    std::cout << CppCon::GetWelcome();
    return 0;
}
```

Then under command line:

```
$ clang++ MyFun.cpp UseFun.cpp -std=c++20 && ./a.out
UseFun.cpp:3:8: fatal error: module 'cppcon' not found
import cppcon;
~~~~~~~^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When did I get wrong, how to solve it?

Comment: I'm very doubtful that clang 14 supports modules. You will need to update to less stable versions.. You also need to enable `-fmodules` flag to enforce this feature.

Comment: You have to build the module (interface file) first; the basic driver doesn’t discover modules in the input files for you.